# Scala - proper way to print a string to file

Tags: string, scala, batch-file, file-io, io

What is the proper way to print a string - and only the string - to file? When I try to do it the standard way known to me, i.e:

```
def printToFile(o:Object,n:String) = try{
  val pathToOutput = "..\\some\\parent\\directory\\"
  val path = Paths.get(pathToOutput + n)

  val b = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
  val os = new ObjectOutputStream(b)
  os.writeObject(o)

  Files.write(path, b.toByteArray,
    StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
    StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING)
}catch{
  case _:Exception => println("failed to write")
}
```

it always seems to prepend

> ¬í NUL ENQtSTXT

Where the part *after* `ENQt` seems to vary.
(Doesn't matter if I declare `o`an Object or a String.)

This is very annoying because I want to print a couple of .dot-Strings (Graphviz) in order to then batch-process the resulting .dot-files to .pdf-files. The prepended nonsense, however, forces me to open each .dot-file and remove it manually - which kind of defeats the purpose of batch-processing them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Scala specifically, it's the way the Java Standard Library works. When you do a `writeObject` you are writing a Serialized representation of the Object, together with a bunch of additional bytes the JVM can use to re-create that object. If you know the object is a `String`, then strong-type it (i.e., use `printToFile(o:String,n:String)` and you can use `Files.write(path, o.getBytes, ...`. Otherwise you could use `o.toString.getBytes`.

Answer (score 2):

Generally in JVM, if you want to write characters and not bytes, you should prefer `*Writer` over `*OutputStream`. In this case (assuming you have a `File` where you want to write and a `String` which you want to write):

```
val writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))
try {
  writer.write(string)
} finally {
  writer.close()
}
```

Or with the character-oriented overload of `Files.write`:

```
Files.write(path, Collections.singletonList(string), ...)
```